# Last SEXTANTE (Processing) update results in missing RScripts examples

Tags: r, sextante, qgis-processing

I have installed today the new version of the Processing plugin on QGIS 2.8 (on Windows 7 x64) and I cannot anymore find the RScripts example that were available (and functioning) before the udpate. Any idea why this have happened? And which are the changes introduced with the latest version of the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: To retrieve R scripts "examples", they have to be installed using the "Get R scripts from on-line scripts collection" tool under the R scripts-> Tools item in the Processing Toolbox. From there, select and download, one by one, many example.